# Current date from BlackBerry

Tags: date, blackberry, java-me, date-format

I am developing an application which needs the current date from the device, but it only needs day-of-week, month, and day-of-month, like `Friday October 14`

I have tried this code with Calendar.  How do I convert Date to String? Is this possible to get date in this format?

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 System.out.println("Date" + c.getTime());

 and my output : `Fri Oct 14 16:17:03 Asia/Calcutta 2011`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.print("Date ");
System.out.println(fmt.format(c.getTime()));
```

If you need those values in different Strings it gets a little bit more complicated (using [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) to get the month/weekday names):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
DateFormatSymbols dateSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
String[] monthsText = dateSymbols.getMonths();
String[] weekdaysText = dateSymbols.getWeekdays();

String day = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String month = monthsText[c.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
String weekday = weekdaysText[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)];

System.out.format("day: %s, month: %s, weekday: %s", day, month, weekday);
```

Comment: `format` returns a string: `String today = fmt.format(c.getTime());`.

Comment: Thanks. how can we split that string (Friday October 14) according  to day,month and date .i want this all field in differ string to set on desire location ?

Comment: @Hitarth: I've edited my answer accordingly. There is no need to split the string - just use the `DateFormatSymbols`to retrieve the month/weekday-names.

Comment: i cant import DateFormatSyambols Class inBlackberry os 5.0